# Unable to define Math Expression for Cloudwatch Alarm in a Cloudformation Template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch

[Recently](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/11/amazon-cloudwatch-launches-ability-to-add-alarms-on-metric-math-expressions/) AWS announced that Cloudwatch alarms can use Math Expressions on metrics. I decided to create an alarm that compares the SUM of 2 single metrics with a given threshold. This means that according to [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/using-metric-math.html#metric-math-syntax) my expression should be SUM([m1,m2]), where m1 and m2 are 2 single metrics.
I also decided to implement this idea using a cloudformation template (in yaml). Here's the Cloudwatch alarm definition:

```
BillingAlarmExpression:
  Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm
  Properties:
    AlarmActions:
      - !Ref BillingAlertTopic
    AlarmDescription: String
    ComparisonOperator: GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold
    EvaluationPeriods: 1
    Metrics:
      - Id: m1
        MetricStat:
          Metric:
            Dimensions:
              - Name: ServiceName
                Value: AmazonEC2
              - Name: Currency
                Value: USD
            MetricName: Estimated­Charges
            Namespace: AWS/Billing
          Period: 86400
          Stat: Maximum
        ReturnData: False
      - Id: m2
        MetricStat:
          Metric:
            Dimensions:
              - Name: ServiceName
                Value: AmazonCloudwatch
              - Name: Currency
                Value: USD
            MetricName: Estimated­Charges
            Namespace: AWS/Billing
          Period: 86400
          Stat: Maximum
        ReturnData: False
      - Id: Expr1
        Expression: SUM([m1,m2])
        Label: Yeap
    Threshold: 100
    TreatMissingData: ignore
```

The single metrics , m1 and m2 , have to do with the billing cost of EC2 and Cloudwatch service. What I want to check is if the charging cost for these 2 services has crossed the threshold of 100$. (Note that since the billing costs are exclusively stored in the N.Virginia region, I tried to deploy the above template in N.Virginia).
During the deployment of this template Cloudformation responds with the following error:

```
"Invalid metrics list (Service: AmazonCloudWatch; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationError; Request ID: c0748047-0378-11e9-ac36-5b1829988d18)"
```

When Cloudformation says "metrics list" it refers to the definition of m1,m2, Expr1. What is even more strange is that when I use the above metrics-list definition from aws cli the charging data return successfully:

```
aws cloudwatch get-metric-data --metric-data-queries file://./metric-data.json --start-time 2018-12-03T03:00:00Z --end-time 2018-12-10T04:30:00Z
```

,where metric-data.json is the above metrics-list.

For creating my template I used the following guides:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cw-alarm.html
and
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/API_GetMetricData.html

Do you have any idea why Cloudformation returns this error? Thanks!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`Id` must start with a lowercase letter, change `Expr1` to `expr1`.

From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/using-metric-math.html):

> You can change the value of Id. It can include numbers, letters, and underscore, and must start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: Yeap! That was the problem! Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome! Don't forget to accept the answer :)

Comment: @P.Str Have you checked if your expression SUM([m1,m2]) is really giving the correct sum? In my case it is not.

Comment: Found due to "Invalid Metrics List"

Comment: really could use some better error messaging here from Amazon.  Thank you.

Comment: Of all the dumb syntax requirements AWS has, this one takes the cake!

Answer (score 2):

I also ran into this issue -- in the off chance that your issue is not the accepted answer (`id` is using lower case), these things are also worth looking out for that can cause the error

- Make sure you're following the proper shape of what a [`MetricDataQuery`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cloudwatch-alarm-metricdataquery.html) looks like and take note which properties are actually optional or not
- Make sure the math expression you're writing is a `String` (surrounded by quotes)
- Make sure you're using proper [`MetricStat`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cloudwatch-alarm-metricstat.html) value (using `Max` instead of `Maximum` can throw this error)

I really hope AWS will look to add better error messaging around this. `Invalid Metrics list` was not very helpful :/

Comment: Also, the Stat's are case sensitive.  `Average`, not `average`