# Terraform Error: creating CloudWatch Alarm ValidationError - Invalid metrics list status code 400

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-cloudwatch, terraform-provider-aws, cloudwatch-alarms

I'm attempting to create a CloudWatch anomaly detector alarm for my Kinesis data stream using Terraform. I made the following setup based on the official Terraform [`xx_anomaly_detection` example](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/cloudwatch_metric_alarm) in their documentation:

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "my_anomaly_detector" {
  alarm_name                = "LowIncomingRecordsAnomaly"
  comparison_operator       = "LessThanLowerThreshold"
  evaluation_periods        = 2
  threshold_metric_id       = "ExpectedIncomingRecords"
  insufficient_data_actions = []

  metric_query {
    id          = "ExpectedIncomingRecords"
    expression  = "ANOMALY_DETECTION_BAND(IncomingRecords, 2)"
    label       = "IncomingRecords (Expected)"
    return_data = "true"
  }

  metric_query {
    id          = "IncomingRecords"
    return_data = "true"
    metric {
      namespace   = "AWS/Kinesis"
      metric_name = "PutRecords.Records"
      stat        = "Sum"
      period      = 300
      unit        = "Count"
      dimensions  = {
        StreamName = "my_stream_name"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, when I run `terraform apply`, I get the following error:

```
Error: creating CloudWatch Metric Alarm (LowIncomingRecordsAnomaly):
ValidationError: Invalid metrics list
        status code: 400, request id: 64e37e0c-4f74-...
```

My code seems to be very comparable to the official doc example, so what would cause this type of error? Unfortunately "ValidationError 400" doesn't say much about the actual issue

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53849899/unable-to-define-math-expression-for-cloudwatch-alarm-in-a-cloudformation-templa), `id` must start with lowercase.
Try to change `IncomingRecords` to `incomingRecords` and `ExpectedIncomingRecords` to `expectedIncomingRecords`.

From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/using-metric-math.html):

> You can change the value of Id. It can include numbers, letters, and
> underscore, and must start with a lowercase letter.

Also I see you used twice `return_data = true` and you can only use it in one `metric_query`, as you can read on this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54792680/aws-cloudwatch-alert-terraform).

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, `id` in the `metric_query` clause seems a lot less variable than implied by the documentation. Someone in this [Github thread](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/8421) mentioned changing around `id` is problematic, and after changing my `id` values to "m1" and "e1" like the documentation example shows fixed my issue:

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "my_anomaly_detector" {
  alarm_name                = "LowIncomingRecordsAnomaly"
  threshold_metric_id       = "e1"
  . . .

  metric_query {
    id          = "e1"
    expression  = "ANOMALY_DETECTION_BAND(m1, 2)"
     . . .
  }

  metric_query {
    id          = "m1"
    metric {
       . . . 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Not sure why this is the case, as I believe these are supposed to be changeable fields, but hopefully this resolves anyone else's problem running into this :)